# This program is running well in visual studio but it is not working perfectly with colours in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, glut

Please find code in the URL below...this code is running well in visual studio but while i run this code in Ubuntu the code is running but in the output only two colors are seen: black and white...but in visual studio i can see multiple colors...

I'm compiling this code using this line:

```
cc -o feedback feedback.c -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lXmu -lXext -lX11 -lm
```

`trippy.c` code:

https://www.cosc.brocku.ca/Offerings/3P98/course/OpenGL/glut-3.7/progs/examples/trippy.c